# Combine smallest elements in one category 'Other' in a pie chart R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a pie chart with only 3 segments.  I want the 2 largest elements and after that all the smallest elements in one category "Other" .  Is there a way to do this directly from a charting package or do I need to manipulate the data set to combine all the smallest values into one.  And is there a quick function to do that?  Thanks for your answers.

Comment: To work in an organized way, good practice would lead you to transform the data, instead of transforming the graph. If using factors your can use [`forcats::fct_reorder()`](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/) to accomplish this. For future reference, please provide an example dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick way of doing is this is by slightly formatting your data set. Since you didn't provide an example, I borrowed one from [the R Graph Gallery](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/piechart-ggplot2.html).

Consider a simple data frame with 5 categories (A to E):

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(
  group=LETTERS[1:5],
  value=c(13,7,9,21,2)
)
```

We can use `rank()` and `ifelse()` to format this data into 3 groups: the two with the largest values and 'Other':

```
plotting_data <- data %>% 
  mutate(rank = rank(-value), 
         group = ifelse(rank <= 2, group, 'Other'))
```

And then simply use this data set for creating the pie chart:

```
ggplot(plotting_data, aes(x="", y=value, fill=group)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1) +
  coord_polar("y", start=0)
```

[image: pie chart with three colours]